# Qt 4: How implement a "Go" button to the QWebView

Tags: c++, qt4, qwebview, qlineedit, qpushbutton

I have 3 objects: a QWebView, a QPushButton and a QLineEdit.

My question is: how to create a connection where when i click the QPushButton, I get the url address in QLineEdit and so, load this url page in QWebView.

Comment: Albert, is the issue resolved now?

Comment: Yes, your class wwork to me. Thanks Laszlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to connect your worker slot to the clicked signal as follows:

```
class MyClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MyClass(QWidget *parent)
            : QWidget(parent)
            , myPushButton("Press Me", this)
            , QLineEdit(this)
            , myWebView(this)
        {
            connect(myPushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(handleClicked(bool));
        }

    public slots:

    void handleClicked(bool)
    {
        myWebView->load(myLineEdit->text());
    }

    private:
        QWebView *myWebView;
        QLineEdit *lineEdit;
        QPushButton *myPushButton;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(loadURL());


void loadURL(bool)
{
    ui->websitecaller->load(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```